# Oracle 12c: Optimal schema design for maintaining revisions

Tags: sql, database, database-design, oracle12c

I have a requirement for maintaining revisions for software documentation books in my project. I have the following tables:

1. Books : book_id, book_name, book_category
2. Book_revisions: Book_id(FK), book_revision_id, book_release_ID(FK), book_developer_id(FK), book_pages, no_of_days, book_start_date, book_finish_date, book_version, latest_flag
3. book_Releases: release_id, release_name, release_date
4. Users: developer_id, developer_email, developer_name

Release date is the one to be used to find the latest release. version is auto-incremented, and unique for a release. Latest_flag is set to Y if the version is the latest for that release.

Now, when I try to get a list of books with latest releases only, here's the query I use:

```
   select book_revision_id, book_id, book_release_ID, book_developer_id, book_pages, no_of_days, book_start_date, book_finish_date, book_version
    from book_revisions r 
    where latest_flag = 'Y'
    and release_id = (select r1.book_release_id from book_revisions r1
    left join book_releases a on a.release_id = r1.book_release_id
    where r1.book_id = r.book_id and r1.latest_flag='Y' and rownum=1
    order by rel.release_date desc)
    and latest_flag='Y'
```

This seems to work, but I am trying to find if this is the best way or there are some standards for designing and querying schema for such revisions requirements?

---

Adding sample data as per one of the comments:
[image]

Comment: Sample data would really help others understand your data structure.

Comment: It very much depends on your needs. One approach (this is in fact my case) is to have two tables, one hosting the **CURRENT** version of objects while a second table (let's call it History) would host previous versions. This approach will not satisfy ALL needs but it does present a suitable approach in my case.

Comment: @GordonLinoff : added an image with example data.

Comment: @FDavidov : in the case you mentioned, how would you maintain current and older versions when new revisions are created? By some db trigger that moves the current revision to the history and keeps the new one as latest?

Comment: EXACTLY!!!!!!!!

Comment: @FDavidov: would you share an example to understand what this trigger looks like?

Comment: @FDavidov: I am asking coz with my current trigger, I am changing the latest _flag for older versions to N and Y for the newly inserted ones. and I am running into error: "Table is mutating, trigger/function may not see it", when I do insert into... select

Comment: @SejalParikh, besides spending some time in trying to help people here, I'm also working on my own projects. So, I can only give you some guidelines (sorry). The error indicates that you are firing a trigger that is supposed to change the table while it changes (sort of recursion). The trigger I suggest should act BEFORE UPDATE and copy the OLD record to the history table (adding few pieces of info like Update timestamp, Update by whom, etc.). One that record was copied, the trigger will proceed and update the record. (continue in another comment...)

Comment: As a result, you will get that the main table will only hold the **CURRENTLY RELEVANT** version of records whereas the history table will host the historical evolution of each and every record. Hope that is of help for you and, if it is, would appreciate you up-vote the comments). Good luck!!!!